# Why are Twist-and-Lock e26 to gu24 not Reverseable

Tags: light-fixture

I recently converted a crane lamp for gu24 LED bulbs, using this [e26-to-gu24 adapter](https://www.mcmaster.com/1528K1/), and found that it was a non-reversible.

Is this because house wiring schemes based on LED lighting will not behave "up-to-code" and as designed if the LED bulbs were replaced by incandescent bulbs, inadvertently, at some later date?

I hate irreversible steps, but will accept this one if there's a good reason.

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the exact product you used to give people some reference. Maybe the particular product you picked is non-reversible, but there are reversible versions available? In what way is it non-reversible? As far as I can tell, an e-26 is a standard screw in lamp base of the type that was common for most of the 20th century in the US. You can't just unscrew it?

Comment: https://www.mcmaster.com/1528K1/. It's referred to as "twist-and-lock". The steel tab which prevents unscrewing is ~1/4" wide and 1/16" tall above the threads (covering two of them) is visible on the small icon in the UR hand corner of the mechanical drawing. You have to destroy the e26 socket being adapted, to separate the gu25 adapter.

Comment: Put the link into the question. Sometimes comments get deleted. That's... odd. The GU24 is the "twist-n-lock" portion. The E26 shouldn't be. I haven't a clue why they would do that, but I'm sure someone here will. Have you tried contacting McMaster-Carr to ask them?

Comment: I apologize for not properly formatting the link: (https://www.mcmaster.com/lighting-accessories/for-bulb-base-type~twist-and-lock/). This pertains to detaching the adapter from the existing socket, not removing the bulb. But as I read more of the comments, the clearer it becomes that in modern homes designed for modern lighting (ie., LED), the NEC wants to prevent someone from reverting to an incandescent where it doesn't belong. DoxyLover and Harper make this point. Thanks to all for bringing me up to speed.

Comment: No worries, Bill. If you'll take the [tour] and browse the [help] you'll find out more of the little "quirks" that set this particular Q&A site apart from most discussion boards.

Answer (score 1):

### Probably to increase reliability.

I have used similar UL-listed units to convert from E26 to Candelabra, and can self-unscrew a bit, and sometimes this affects contact.  In fact, *they do it a lot* when unscrewing a bulb - I usually get the bulb with the adapter still on it. Which is fine for my application.

This "self-unscrew" would be particularly annoying for a G-family bulb, where you only turn 20-30 degrees to release, but you must overcome a pretty strong detent that is extra sticky from years of not moving.  The detent would be stronger than unscrew force, so like me you'd get the bulb with adapter together.  *Now what?* How do you separate them?  The adapter is too little to put that kind of torque on bare-handed, and now you're looking for a pair of Vice Grips or Channel-Loks. Which will damage the adapter.

McMaster primarily sells to institutions (their original market was the railway and mining industry) and most of those institutions are doing conversions with a "don't look back" philosophy. Hence, using a one-way ratchet favors the use-case of these adapters.

Answer (score 0):

In many jurisdictions (e. g. California), power saving lights are required for new construction and standard Edison screw-base sockets are forbidden to prevent later installation of incandescent bulbs. Allowing the user to add an adapter to allow an incandescent bulb to be installed in a power-saving fixture would defeat the purpose.

In addition, as @harper noted in his answer, putting a high-wattage incandescent or halogen bulb in a fixture designed for low wattage power-saving bulbs may be a safety hazard.

Comment: Why the downvote? I my information is incorrect, please let me know so I can correct it. I'm not perfect and still want to learn.

Comment: _If_ I were to downvote, it would be for the state of Kalifornistan mandating more things on its people. That, however, wouldn't be fair to you, so it wasn't me.

Comment: Unless the downvoter pops up to explain themselves, I’m at a loss. The information is accurate. (Google Title 24.)